# Regex for replacing character within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two test strings:

```
1+":"+2:xyz
1+"a:fb"+2:xyz
```

I am trying to replace the : which is between quotes.

I tried this:

```
(".*):(.*")
```

replacing with:

```
$1Q$2
```

but I end up with this:

```
1+"Q"+2:xyz
1+"Q"+2:xyz
```

but I want to end up with this:

```
1+"Q"+2:xyz
1+"aQfb"+2:xyz
```

Can somebody help me out please.  Must work in Javascript.

EDIT:

I have switched my testing tool to one that works properly (namely doing it directly in javascript in a browser).

This now works:

```
var str = '1+"a:fb"+2:xyz';
var res = str.replace(/(".*):(.*")/g, "$1Q$2");
```

but what if I have two : in two sets of quotes, like so:

```
1+"a:fb"+2+":"
```

I now get this result:

```
1+"a:fb"+2+"Q":xyz
```

Comment: What's up with all those backslashes in your regex? No voodoo escaping. Escape the things that must be escaped, and only those things.

Comment: I've always escaped quotes - looks like I don't need to - have changed it now

Comment: Doesn't your approach work as expected? https://regex101.com/r/sogO6I/1

Comment: Hmm - must be the test tool I'm using - cheers Danilo

Comment: @Graham There is no need to escape quotes in a regex literal (delimited by `/`). There is a need to escape quotes in a string literal. This is a requirement of string literals and has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: FYI your "new" code only works if there's only exactly one quoted string on each input line. Otherwise it will still break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively you are trying to replace a pattern that consists of three parts:

1. a bit that starts with a `"` and contains neither `"` nor `:`
2. a `:`
3. a bit that contains neither `"` nor `:` and ends with a `"`

so the expression would look like:

```
("[^:"]*):([^:"]*")
```

substituted for `$1Q$2` this results in

```
1+"Q"+2:xyz
1+"aQfb"+2:xyz
```

The reason why yours did not work properly lies in [greedy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: Ah ha - this works for my edited version - thank you

Comment: Be sure to take some time to meditate over greedy matching. It has potential to bite you, it has potential to be a very efficient tool. Knowing how it works is key.